# Android: how to calculate dpi from a design?

Tags: android, layout

I have a 800 x 480 (landscape) design made in photoshop and now I'm trying to implement the same design on Android.

How am I supposed to calculate width and height for a LinearLayout? For example, a header has 800px width and 60px height. How many DPI they are?

The min and the target SDK are 14. Am I need to worry for devices that are using a smaller display? (Smaller than 480x800) ? (I don't know if older devices can run Android 4+)

I have tested on my AVD (Nexus 7) and this is how it's look (accordingly to my photoshop design):

[image]

But on a tablet:

[image]

**Am I need to create different layouts for different devices?**

Comment: I suspect that you might be asking the wrong question.  What are you trying to achieve?  Image full screen regardless of screen size?

Comment: Yes. I want to display the same view (image - ratio) on the tablet as on the phone.

Comment: Use `android:scaleType` in the ImageView XML declaration.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html  You probably want `CENTER_INSIDE` or `FIT_CENTER`

Comment: I don't need to define the ImageView margins? On phone I have defined margins (10dpi from left, and 10 dpi from the top).

Comment: That doesn't matter.  The image will be scaled taking into account margin and padding.  Why not just try it? ;)

Comment: If you also need to scale up your images (with loss of quality), also provide `adjustImageBounds="true"` (plus what @Simon said)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that you need to understand - for which density your design is. Most common situation is design in mdpi, which means that 1dp on device (with mdpi screen) will be equivalent to 1px of design layout. On devices with higher density it will be increased accordingly (4:6:8 rule).

Second thing - providing values in dp **won't** magically scale up your layout for **larger** devices. Note, that dpi **is not** the same as screen resolution. So, for example, large 10inch tablet with 1280x800 screen resolution is **mdpi** device (not hdpi, not xhdpi).

Third. It makes no sense to say "800x600 device is smaller that 1280x800", because they may both be, for example, 4inch phone.

Fourth. Screen resolution have nothing to do with SDK version.

What you need to do, is look for another design for larger devices or ask designer about what he wanted to see. Maybe images shouldn't be strictly sized in dp, maybe they should be sized in percentage of the occupied screen?

Comment: Exactly, percentage of the occupied screen. All I want to know is how to calculate DPI for each device. I have seen somewhere a list of the devices (density).

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian if we're talking about percentage - there is no point in measuring it in dp. Let's measure it in percents :) For such purpose you can use `LinearLayout` and provide it's children with `layout_weight` param (somewhat similar to percentage that you're looking for).

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian and don't forget that `ImageView` won't scale up it's image. For more information - check comments below your question.